# Check if exact string is inside "innerHTML"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if the string `ft-file` is inside my innerHTML variable. It need to be the exact match including the hyphen.

A small aberration shouldn't be a match, for example "ft-file2", should be false, too.

I tried it with a "regex" but I get the wrong result (false). This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5djnepw/) and the code.

```js
 let text = document.getElementsByClassName("fulltext")[0].innerHTML;
var reg = /^ft-file$/;

if (reg.test(text) == true) {
    console.log("true");
} else {
    console.log("false")
}
```

```html
<div class="fulltext">
   [test="data/ft-file/images/small/red"]
</div>
```

Comment: `^ft-file$` looks for a **line** that is exactly `ft-file` - your string isn't in a line by itself `/\bft-file\b/` may work - but, beware [Tony the pony, he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Keroster, added a solution, check if that addresses your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

A lookbehind `(?<=/)` and a lookahead `(?=\/)` matches only if `ft-file` is followed by a `/` and is following a `/`.

You need to escape the hyphen

```
/(?<=\/)ft\-file(?=\/)/g
```

The characters that need to be escaped (prefixed with `\`) are:

```
-
^
\
]
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bC546J/1)

```js
let txt = document.querySelector(".fulltext").innerHTML;
const rgx = /(?<=\/)ft\-file(?=\/)/g;
let match = rgx.test(txt);
console.log(match);
```

```html
<div class="fulltext">
  [test="data/ft-file/images/small/red"]
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the exact match. `ft-file2` would be a match, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrapped in `^` and `$`, which mean start and end of the line, respectively. This means it would only match if that was the only content in `innerHTML`

Setting your regex to be `/ft-file/` will achieve what you are looking for.

See regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/PMVxBp/1

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work as expected. I need the exact match. With your solution `ft-file2` would be a match, too.

Answer (score 0):

it should be as simple as searching as "ft-file" or "(ft-file)" and expecting not digit and non-character before and after. It captures the result as a group

Try this

```
 [\W\D](ft-file)[\W\D]
```

https://regex101.com/r/20U1yJ/1

Comment: Keroster, check if that addresses your question

Comment: Do you mean like that https://jsfiddle.net/8Lb6mdu4/1/? I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: ft is not defined".

Comment: [\W\D](ft-file)[\W\D], you find it here https://regex101.com/r/20U1yJ/1

Comment: within in javascript you need to enclose the pattern in forward slash   var reg = /[\W\D](ft-file)[\W\D]/g;

Comment: updated the code here  https://jsfiddle.net/j8qoufy9/